# TurboC - malloc() in "compact" memory model

Tags: c, malloc, dos, memory-model, turbo-c

I am using good old Borland's TurboC compiler for DOS. When I use `malloc()` on `compact` memory model and write anything to the allocated memory, program freezes at some point (I suspect `malloc()` returns pointer to somewhere I shouldn't write). When I do the same on `small` memory model, it works fine.

I took a look on the allocated memory and the pointer the `malloc()` returns, using this small piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char *x;
unsigned int i;
unsigned int mds, mss;

#define X(a) x[i+(a)]

int main(void) {

    // show current SS and DS
    asm {
        mov AX, DS
        mov mds, AX
        mov AX, SS
        mov mss, AX
    }
    printf("ds=%04x, ss=%04x\n", mds, mss);

    // allocate memory and show the pointer
    x = (unsigned char*)malloc(128);
    printf("x=%p\n", x);

    // write out contents of the allocated memory
    for (i = 0; i < 128; i += 16)
        printf("%p: %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x\n", &x[i], X(0), X(1), X(2), X(3), X(4), X(5), X(6), X(7), X(8), X(9), X(10), X(11), X(12), X(13), X(14), X(15));

    free(x);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this for `small` memory model, I get:

```
tcc -ms -IC:\turboc\include -LC:\turboc\lib -etest.exe test.c

ds=02f9, ss=02f9
x=05f2
05f2: 00 00 00 ... 00
0602: 00 00 00 ... 00
...
0662: 00 00 00 ... 00
```

When I do the same with `compact` memory model, I get:

```
tcc -mc -IC:\turboc\include -LC:\turboc\lib -etest.exe test.c

ds=034f, ss=0391
x=0000:0004
0000:0004: 08 00 70 00 ... 08 00 70 00
0000:0014: 54 ff 00 f0 ... a5 fe 00 f0
...
0000:0074: a4 f0 00 f0 ... 60 14 00 f0
```

The pointer `0000:0004` looks suspicious to me and I suspect it to point somewhere outside the heap. I do not recognize the contents, but if I write to the memory, the program freezes.

What am I doing wrong and what should I do to get correct pointer from `malloc()`? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: "Good old DOS", eh?  I'll agree with you about the "old", anyway... :-)

Comment: You really don't need that `X()` macro, you know.

Comment: Don't use TurboC, and don't use MSDOS unless you are forced to. Consider installing some free operating system (e.g. some [linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution)...) on your PC, even if it is an old one. Use some standard conforming C compiler (at least for [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)...). You surely have more than [640K](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/09/08/640k-enough/) of memory these days, so install an OS and compiler taking advantage of them

Comment: If you are interested in [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/), use that forum for such questions

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is obsolete (or should be asked on [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/))

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Thank You for pointing me to retrocomputing, did not know that site. I do it for fun.

Comment: Feel free to ask programming related questions here. Despite Basile Starynkevitch's comments, there's no rule against asking questions related to obsolete technologies.

Comment: @RossRidge : Glad I'm not the only one that thought that.

Comment: This bug is older than DOS, however... missing stdlib.h. It's a very well-known flaw in the long since obsolete C90 standard. You should start to smell a rat when different memory model -> different pointer size. In small memory model the pointers were likely 16 bit just like `int`. When pointers got bigger than the size of an `int`, the compiler went bananas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to an old reference manual, including `<stdlib.h>` should fix this.  (Compilers on other systems would print a warning for this code, too.)

Without a prototype, `malloc` is implicitly declared as returning `int`.  The returned `int` value is automatically converted to a pointer.  But in the compact memory model, pointers and `int`s do not have the same representation, so the implicit declaration and conversion do not yield the correct value.

Pretty much same thing happens with implicitly declared `malloc` on 64-bit UNIX-like platforms.

Comment: Thanks, good point with the implicit `malloc()` return type. Too bad that the compiler doesn't even warn me.

Answer (score 4):

If memory serves me correctly if you want memory allocation to behave as expected with memory models that use far and huge pointers you have to include  `alloc.h`. Try adding this to your file:

```
#include <alloc.h>
```

Comment: You shall be proud of Your memory, this is the right solution, it solved my problem! Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Just wanted to say that this saved my bacon today with uses of `farmalloc`, from a program crashing while loading to everything working, just by adding that header :D